# Are these all ironies?

Tags: meaning

> It had twelve hands but no numbers; instead, little planets were
>   moving around the edge. It must have made sense to Dumbledore, though,
>   because he put it back in his pocket and said, "Hagrid's late. I
>   suppose it was he who told you I'd be here, by the way?"   "Yes," said
>   Professor McGonagall. "And **I don't suppose you're going to tell me
>   why you're here**, of all places?" "I've come to bring Harry to his
>   aunt and uncle. They're the only family he has left now."  "You don't
>   mean -- you can't mean the people who live here?" cried Professor
>   McGonagall, jumping to her feet and pointing at number four.
>   "Dumbledore - you can't. I've been watching them all day. **You
>   couldn't find two people who are less like us**. And they've got this
>   son -- I saw him kicking his mother all the way up the street,
>   screaming for sweets. **Harry Potter come and live here**!"  (Harry
>   Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Are all there highlighted parts ironies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of the three highlighted sentences are ironic, although the first, being mild  [sarcasm](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sarcasm#Noun)¹, borders on irony.  The second sentence is an exaggerated statement of fact; the third, an expression of indignation.  Neither of the latter two contains any element of irony.

¹Sarcasm is “a form of humor that is marked by mocking with irony, sometimes conveyed in speech with vocal over-emphasis. Insincerely saying something which is the opposite of one's intended meaning, often to emphasize how unbelievable or unlikely it sounds if taken literally, thereby illustrating the obvious nature of one's intended meaning”.